# on first click > event.preventDefault(), if same element looses focus reset this process

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, click, event-listener

Returning false in a "one" jquery function would do the trick:

```
firstClickDisable: function(){
    this.$el.one('click', false);
}
```

But it will also prevent me from using other click Event-handlers on that element

my problem is that the default action is executed at the second click on the element regardless if I was clicking somewhere else in the meantime.

I want it to only do the default action if the second click is the immediate follow-up click of the first one. If the user was clicking anywhere else and the element would loose focus i want it to prevent the `firstClick` again.

I tried comparing the element with `document.activeElement` but since I can only do this in the event listener, the element is always the `activeElement`.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you want to listen for a double-click event https://api.jquery.com/dblclick/

Comment: Thank you @freedomn-m, not exactly as i don't want a limited timeout between the clicks.

Comment: You can reapply your firstclick event when the element loses focus using blur: `this.$el.on("blur", this.$el.on('click', ...`  might need a little extra work so that it doesn't occur more than once (eg tab on/tab off rather than clicking)

Comment: That might be worth a shot, thanks